# Fastest way to sort multidimensional array with dates in chronological order

Tags: javascript, sorting, momentjs

I have a date in the format below

```
[
    ["First Name", "10 Sep. 2017 2:00 PM"],
    ["First Name", "10 Sep. 2017 2:00 PM"],
    ["First Name", "10 Sep. 2017 1:00 PM"],
    ["First Name", "10 Sep. 2017 8:00 AM"],
    ["First Name", "9 Sep. 2017 2:00 PM"],
    ["First Name", "9 Sep. 2017 2:00 PM"],
    ["First Name", "9 Sep. 2017 1:00 PM"],
    ["First Name", "9 Sep. 2017 8:00 AM"]
]
```

And want this to be the output:

```
[
    ["First Name", "10 Sep. 2017 8:00 AM"],
    ["First Name", "10 Sep. 2017 1:00 PM"],
    ["First Name", "10 Sep. 2017 2:00 PM"],
    ["First Name", "10 Sep. 2017 2:00 PM"],
    ["First Name", "9 Sep. 2017 8:00 AM"],
    ["First Name", "9 Sep. 2017 1:00 PM"],
    ["First Name", "9 Sep. 2017 2:00 PM"],
    ["First Name", "9 Sep. 2017 2:00 PM"]
]
```

Notice how the dates are in order but the times were changed chronologically. In other words, the times were reversed. How can I do this? Here is my code before that I have to generate the first sample array

```
function sortTable(data) {

  return sortTableHelper(data);

  function sortTableHelper(data) {
   data = data.sort((elem1, elem2) => {
     var date1 = moment(elem1[1], 'D MMM YYYY h:m A')
       , date2 = moment(elem2[1], 'D MMM YYYY h:m A');

     if (date1.isAfter(date2)) return 1;

     return -1;
   });

   return data;
 }
}
```

How can I modify the existing sort code that I have to put the times in chronological order?

Answer (score 2):

You have to sort by date without the hours and by the hours to get your desired result, like this:

```js
var input = [["First Name", "10 Sep. 2017 2:00 PM"], ["First Name", "10 Sep. 2017 2:00 PM"], ["First Name", "10 Sep. 2017 1:00 PM"], ["First Name", "10 Sep. 2017 8:00 AM"], ["First Name", "9 Sep. 2017 2:00 PM"], ["First Name", "9 Sep. 2017 2:00 PM"], ["First Name", "9 Sep. 2017 1:00 PM"], ["First Name", "9 Sep. 2017 8:00 AM"]];

function sortTable(data) {

  return sortTableHelper(data);

  function sortTableHelper(data) {

   return data.sort((a, b) => {
     var dateA = new Date(a[1]);
     var dateB = new Date(b[1]);
 
     return dateA.getHours() - dateB.getHours() + dateB.setHours(0) - dateA.setHours(0);
   });
 }
}

console.log(sortTable(input));
```

**Note**: Done without `momentjs`.

Answer (score 1):

Invert the return code so your results are ascending rather than descending:

```
if (date2.isAfter(date1)) return 1;
if (date1.isAfter(date2)) return -1;
return 0;
```

Note I changed the code to return 0 when the items are equal.